# G Suite and Django for SMTP

Tags: django, django-settings, google-workspace

I'm in the process of getting G Suite to work with my django site so that it will replace the SMTP server of my host. I configured my domain within my webhost's config panel. As a result, when I send an email to support@mysite.com, I can see that it successfully comes though to the Google Account, which is great.

My application is setup to send out a confirmation email after someone tries to register.

I've completed what I believe to be all of the required steps to setup G Suite with my django project, but I still get an error when my project attempts to send out the confirmation email after someone registers. Specifically, I'm seeing the following on the Django error page:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected at /access/register/ Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I've completed the following steps:

1.I've setup the SMTP relay service (https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491), which means I've:

- turned on comprehensive mail storage as per the instructions
- added the SMTP relay service setting
- allowed less secure apps (https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) in my settings

2.In my django settings files, I'm using the following settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@mysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'support@mysite.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'support@mysite.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

I should also mention that with the following settings, my app was able to send out validation emails following registration with the webhost's SMTP server before I started down the path of implementing G Suite, so that I know that that part of the app works.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mywebhost.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'support@mysite.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'support@mysite.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

I'm pretty certain I'm missing something on the G Suite configuration side and I was hoping that you could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Accoding to the documentation of GSuite here : **https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491**

If you are using "**EMAIL_USE_TLS=False**" then you will have to use some other authentication for the SMTP server like "**IP Address Authentication**".

If you do not setup the IP address filter in GSuite settings, your connection will the "unexpectedly closed".

Please try the point no 8 in the help page link above.